# Html list display in block with css

Tags: css

I got a list of menu items i have to separate like this:

```
item1
item2
item3
item4
item5
item6
item7
item8
item9
item10
```

But i have to display the in this kind of order:

```
item 1     item4     item8
item 2     item5     item9
item 3     item6     item10
item 4     item7
```

I tried to use the code below, but its not working as I described above.

```
li{
    display: inline;
}
li:after{
    content:"\A"; 
    white-space:pre; 
}
```

Is it even possible to display list item with css modifications like this?

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```css
.container {
  width: 250px;
}
ul {
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-gap: 5px;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-gap: 5px;
  column-count: 3;
  column-gap: 5px;
}

li {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
    <li>Item 7</li>
    <li>Item 8</li>
    <li>Item 9</li>
    <li>Item 10</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @navitua if this solution satisfies you, please accept the answer.  If not, please indicate what isn't quite right to the volunteer so that he can edit.  Please always progress your questions toward a system-recognized resolution, because this shows your appreciation to the volunteer and helps future researchers to know that this answer works.

Answer (score 0):

Use this css:

```
ul{
        width: 90px;
    }
    li{
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    width: 30px;
}
li:after{
    content:"\A"; 
    white-space:pre; 
}
```

you can set a maximum width on ul and than divided in li as you required.

Comment: wouldn't that list them across not down?

Comment: you can just play with width of ul li, or you can more in separate div.